# How can I evaluate an xt::xfunction (from xtensor, in c++) directly into "byte data"?

Tags: c++, xtensor

If I have a piece of data reserved, that I know is the correct length:

```
uint8_t * data; 
size_t length;
```

How can I evaluate an xfunction directly into the data?

i.e.

```
template <typename ... whatever>
void putinto(uint8_t* data, size_t datalenifneeded, xt::xfunction<whatever...> f) {
    // now what?
    // something like xtensorbytewisewrapper(data) = f?
}
```

...WITHOUT creating an intermediate container value: the xfunction should evaluate directly into the *data, which may be on the heap or stack.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible without any container storing at least strides. Maybe `xtensor_fixed` could do it, because it might rely fully in templating for it, but I'm not sure to be honest. If you don't might about some container consider `xt::adapt`